# How to post static file with urlfetch?

Tags: google-app-engine, post, urlfetch

Let's say I have the following handler in my `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /img/
  static_dir: templates/img
```

and that `templates/img` folder contains file `0001.jpg`.

The following code is used to POST the data:

```
parameters = {'parm1': 'value1', 
    'parm2': 'value2'}
parameters = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
response = urlfetch.Fetch(url, payload=parameters, method=urlfetch.POST, deadline=60)
```

How should I add that file to `urlfetch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, static files in App Engine are *not* accessible by the application. As [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) explain, "Static files are not available in the application's file system".

If you need a file to be both served statically **and** readable by the application, you can add `application_readable: true` to the `static_dir` handler stanza.

However, if you do that, again per the doc, the files will be uploaded twice (to your app's filesystem and to the separate one from which static files are served), and "Both uploads are charged against your code and static data storage resource quotas".

If you do that, your application code (assuming it lives in the top level directory of which `templates` is a sub-directory) will be able to access the file you mention (for reading, only) at a path given by:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/img/0001.jpg')
```

Even then, I don't know what you mean by "add that file to urlfetch". `urlfetch.Fetch` does not accept a file argument. If you mean to add the file's contents to the `payload`, then presumably you'd just add an entry with it (with the name you want to use, and the file's bytes as the value) to the dictionary you are urlencoding for the purpose, e.g

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    parameters['data'] = f.read()
```

just before the call to `urlencode`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I want to simulate file upload, so file's content should be added to the `payload`. But your approach doesn't work - I've checked what local server sends - it doesn't generate `boundary` in the request, so file is passed just as string.

Comment: If you need to encode the parameters as multipart form data, you could use functionality from Python's standard library's `email` package, or e.g the recipe at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578668-encode-multipart-form-data-for-uploading-files-via/ . How to best encode data as multipart form data is a separate issue from the one of where the data you're encoding comes from (e.g, a "static file" in App Engine) or how you're then using the encoded payload (e.g for urlfetch).

Comment: OK, usage of `poster` library helped me. But I've tested and - I can read files even when I don't indicate `application_readable: true`.

Comment: @LA_, you can probably accidentally read them locally, but, if they're in a static handler directive, without `application_readable: true`, they won't be uploaded when you deploy and thus your app code won't be able to read them.

Comment: I've renamed the file, removed the folder from `app.yaml` and uploaded it to production server - it works, the file can be read.

Comment: Sure, if it's not in a static handler directive (which I imagine is what you mean by "removed the folder from `app.yaml`") then it will be uploaded and readable, NP. But, you do have "static file" in your Q's title, and it starts right out with a static handler directive, so that's a very different issue! If you don't need files statically served then don't put them in a static handler directive, which can serve no useful purpose in that case.